# Is there a comprehensive list of types, functions at compile time in cython namespace?

Tags: python, cython

I can find list of functions which I can cimport from libc, libcpp, cpython, etc in *.pxd files inside Includes folder of Cython package.

However, I can not find such a list for cython.

For example, I know I can do this

```
from cython.view cimport array
```

However, I do not know what else I can cimport from cython.

Where do I find a comprehensive list of things cimportable from cython namespace (either in documentation or source codes)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. A lot of them are [compiler directives, and are documented](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#compiler-directives).

However, there's definitely some directives which aren't documented [because they're only for internal testing use](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/HackerGuide#parse-tree-assertions) or are old and no longer recommended or just haven't been documented.

The majority appear in [Cython/Compiler/Shadow.py](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Shadow.py) largely as dummy declarations just so they exist and thus pure-python mode works. However, this isn't hugely readably and doesn't really tell you what they do.

The contents of `cython.view` are a further exception and are generated internally by the compiler. I think (but not 100% sure) that this is the only such exception.

Mostly it isn't really a useful exercise to be trying to find things in the `cython` namespace that aren't documented.

Comment: Where can I find the contents of cython.view? Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Utility/MemoryView.pyx but there's also some stuff that comes from related C utility code files